# Best text documents organizer for linux?

Tags: linux, organizer-software

I am looking for something to organize information I have in text files. My hdd is full of text files containing email logins, cpanel logins, urls, and things like that and it's getting harder to find some stuff now.

I dont need any calendar or contact address features, just good features to organize text documents/notes.

Can someone recommend a software to organize this information? I'd like to have categories and maybe "notes" for each stored document so it would be easier to identify what's inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not meant to organise and categorise *existing* text documents, [KeepNote](http://keepnote.org/) is text-based (XML), is very easy to use, and allows creation of "notebooks" - which is a bunch of related "folders" and "pages".  Also, cross-platform. :)

For your purposes, I'd copy the info into separate "pages" within KeepNote and continue from there.

If a lot of your information is private and contains login/password details, you may want to consider [KeePass](http://keepass.info/) - simple, easy-to-use password manager which encrypts the data to your disk.  Also, cross-platform installers exist. :)

Answer (score 1):

Using Google Desktop or other file content indexer may be an option. Instead of manually adding additional metadata like notes (based on data already in a file), maintaining categories and manually searching for a file you just type keywords.